# Sitecore redirect to login page from sessionEnd pipeline

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

Hello I would like have some functionality on sesstion expired event,
I have created next pipleline for sitecore. after my custom action I need to make redirect to login page. but I got excetion on redirect action.

```
 public class SessionEnd2
    {
        public  void Process(SessionEndArgs endArgs)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(endArgs, "args");
            //do some stuff here
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
            //WebUtil.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);

        }
    }
```

It seems like I can't redirect in this type of piplelines. 
But I need have way to show user login page.
settings in web.config is not works not in None nor Forms mode

```
 <authentication mode="None">
      <forms  name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="1" slidingExpiration="false" defaultUrl="~/main.aspx"    />
  </authentication>


   в System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   в System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   в System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url)
   в MyLib.SessionEnd2.Process(SessionEndArgs endArgs) в d:\Projects\MyProj\Website\SessionEnd.cs:строка 30
   в (Object , Object[] )
   в Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineMethod.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
   в Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   в Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   в Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What is the exact exception? It would be useful to know

Comment: nullreferenceexception put stacktrace to main body

Comment: can you get a reference to the httpcontext from endArgs? Sorry, I don't have access to Sitecore just now to check

Comment: yes it exist as I can see

Comment: Rolling back to the actual requirement - it looks like you are re-inventing forms authentication. Do you just want the user to be redirected to a login page when their session expires?

Comment: yes. it is part of requirements.

Comment: Maybe you could check out this link: http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/08/Authentication-Options-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Session end is managed by the server, so there is no client request or response associated with it. The error you are seeing is most likely caused by `HttpContext.Current.Response` being null.

Instead of tapping into the `sessionEnd` pipeline, you might consider hooking into `httpRequestBegin` and checking for the presence of a Session variable on every request:

```
if (Session["Username"] == null)
    // Redirect to login page
```

Alternatively, you can periodically call a web service via JavaScript to check the status of the Session. The benefit here is that you can warn the user that the session is about to time out, and offer to stay logged in.

Comment: thanks but how to check how much time before session is expired ?

Comment: @a3code one way is to use the `window.setTimeout` JavaScript method to trigger the warning a minute or two before the session ends.

Comment: If you keep checking the session you will need to make sure that the request to check isn't keeping the session alive!

Answer (score 0):

If endArgs has a Context property you might be able to do something like:

```
endArgs.Context.Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx");
```